# how to read xml file content from file in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm sure this question has been asked before but i can't find it in Stakoverflow
i'm doing a simple site where you upload an xml and it parses it to json.
i'm having a form to upload the xml:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Upload file:
          <input
            type="file"
            ref={input => {
              this.App = input;
            }}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

and my lisenter:

```
 handleSubmit(event) {

    //here the file will be opened
    //submit pressed


    event.preventDefault();
    alert(
      `Selected file - ${this.App.files[0].name}`

    );
  }
```

how do i extract the xml content from the file in the event ?
i want to have a String with the xml content from the file

thnx !!!

Answer (score 0):

Found it i used this code:

```
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var allText;
    rawFile.open("GET", this.App.files[0], false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                allText = rawFile.responseText;
                // alert(allText);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
```